# How do I turn on Greasemonkey live editing?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, greasemonkey, userscripts

On Firefox, I click Tools, Addons, Extensions, Greasemonkey, Options, select my user script, click Edit, change the source code, reload one of the included pages, but the script is the unchanged version.

On User Scripts, logged in, I click my username, Script Management, my script's name, Admin, Edit Code Online, change the source code, click save, the link to the install page, install and the script is the changed version.

How do you turn on Live Editing?  While following Greasemonkey tutorials, this feature is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! It's here: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Editing

Greasemonkey has to edit the copy of the original script that is in the Firefox profile folder. To make Greasemonkey do that, you have to move the original script to the Recycle Bin, because then it'll prompt for the script location again and then you'll be able to select the copy of the original script that is in the Firefox profile folder.

Answer (score 0):

As of Nov 3 2017, it's no longer possible to edit scripts directly due to limitations imposed by the WebExtension API surface.

https://wiki.greasespot.net/index.php?title=Greasemonkey_Manual%3AEditing&type=revision&diff=7568&oldid=7427

The API has become much more locked down over time, naturally. Unfortunate, however, since it means less people will be writing scripts due to being forced to use an embedded editor.